# Как сделать session cookie в Laravel независимыми от часового пояса?

Tags: laravel, timezone, сессия, cookie, symfony

Куки, которой Laravel метит браузер посетителя для поддержания сессий, уходит с параметром `expires` в абсолютном времени, в часовом поясе сервера. Серверный и php'шный пояс у меня стоит UTC.

Время жизни сессии 120 минут. У посетителей из Красноярска (+7) кука приходит с временем expires 5 часов назад. Пример заголовка ответа:

> Set-Cookie  my_app_session=XXX..XXX%3D; expires=Sun, 21-Sep-2014 09:57:16 GMT; path=/; httponly

Ошибка Laravel? Может, кто-то уже сталкивался – как починить? Застрял в дебрях классов Illuminate и Symfony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался. `app/config/session.php':

```
'expire_on_close' => true,
```

С этой настройкой куки будут выдаваться без даты Expire, что делает из них session cookies — на время сеанса.